# How do you append data with matching ids from a different table without duplicating rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to pull data from one table to add into an existing query. Essentially, I want to bring over only the PM and Supt names and add them to rows with corresponding employee ids. Tables 1 and 2 in the illustration below are examples of the 2 tables I am trying to "merge" data from and Table 3 is what I am hoping to get as a result.

```
Table 1:
+--------+----------+
| Emp_ID | Emp_Name |
+--------+----------+
| 1111   | Bob      |
+--------+----------+
| 2222   | Joe      |
+--------+----------+

Table 2:
+------+------+
| PM   | Supt |
+------+------+
| 1111 | 2222 |
+------+------+
| 1111 | 3333 |
+------+------+

Table 3 (Expected Result):
+------+------+---------+-----------+
| PM   | Supt | PM_Name | Supt_Name |
+------+------+---------+-----------+
| 1111 | 2222 | Bob     | Joe       |
+------+------+---------+-----------+
| 1111 |      | Bob     | NULL      |
+------+------+---------+-----------+
```

So far I have been able to get the employee name to show up in the correct fields with a left join and a case statement but I get duplicated rows (one for each name instance). I have included my current code and example result set for reference as well.

```
    SELECT 
                     JUDF.Job_Number, JUDF.User_Def_Sequence, JUDF.Date_Field, JUDF.Company_Code, JUDF.Alpha_Field, JM.Original_Contract, JM2.Revised_Contract, JM.Job_Description, JM.Project_Manager, JM.Superintendent, 
                     (CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(JM.Project_Manager)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(ECL.Employee_Code)) THEN ECL.Employee_Name END) AS PM_Name, (CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(JM.Superintendent)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(ECL.Employee_Code)) 
                     THEN ECL.Employee_Name END) AS Supt_Name
    FROM            dbo.JC_JOB_MASTER_MC AS JM INNER JOIN
                     dbo.JC_JOB_USER_FIELDS_DET_MC AS JUDF WITH (NOLOCK) ON JM.Company_Code = JUDF.Company_Code AND JM.Job_Number = JUDF.Job_Number INNER JOIN
                     dbo.JC_JOB_MASTER2_MC AS JM2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON JM.Company_Code = JM2.Company_Code AND JM.Job_Number = JM2.Job_Number LEFT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.Z_EMPLOYEE_CODE_LIST AS ECL WITH (NOLOCK) ON LTRIM(RTRIM(JM.Project_Manager)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(ECL.Employee_Code)) OR
                     LTRIM(RTRIM(JM.Superintendent)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(ECL.Employee_Code))

+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+---------+-----------+
| Job_Number | User_Def_Seq | Date_Field | Company_Code | Alpha_Field | Original_Contract | Revised_Contract | Job_Description | Project_Manager | Superintendent | PM_Name | Supt_Name |
+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+---------+-----------+
| 12345      | 001          | NULL       | ABC          | NULL        | 12345             | 12345            | Test            | 1111            | 2222           | Bob     | NULL      |
+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+---------+-----------+
| 12345      | 001          | NULL       | ABC          | NULL        | 12345             | 12345            | Test            | 1111            | 2222           | NULL    | Joe       |
+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Be careful using NOLOCK all over the place. That hints does things like randomly return missing and/or duplicate rows in addition to many other exciting "features". https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join to the ECL table twice.  Once for the PMs, and once for the SUPTS.   Trying to use a single join with `OR` will result in duplicate rows with NULLs instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* almost what your looking for it has a null where there is blank lol*/
```

> select a.empid, b.empid, a.empname , b.empnam from table2 c left join
>   table1 a on pm = a.empid left join table2 b on supt = b.empid

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @r table(Emp_ID int, Emp_Name varchar(25))
declare @t table(PM int, Supt int)

insert into @r
select 1111, 'Bob'
insert into @r
select 2222, 'Joe'

insert into @t
select 1111,2222
insert into @t
select 1111,3333

select t.PM, t.Supt, r.Emp_Name as PM_Name, rr.Emp_Name
from @t t
left join @r r on t.PM = r.Emp_ID
left join @r rr on rr.Emp_ID = t.Supt
```